# MediaWiki REMOTE_USER auto-login with AuthManager

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, mediawiki

The authentication mechanism has been revamped in version 1.27 of MediaWiki; it now uses AuthManager instead of AuthPlugin. Can someone provide any tips on how one could go about re-spinning the Extension:Auth_remoteuser auto-login feature using $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']? My understanding is that I would need to implement an Authentication Provider, but I'm not sure where to start. Update: A code example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your question has been answered elsewhere, but for the record there is [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager) and an [update guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager/Updating_tips) available, and as [explained there](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager#SessionProvider), you probably want to implement `ImmutableSessionProviderWithCookie`. The phpdoc for that class and its parents has further instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen these, but a code example would have been nice. I did get my answer elsewhere, though, in this [discussion](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T110292).